# Custom pdf viewer in android

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I need to have a custom pdf viewer inside my application where i have my own menu and all.
It is not working with webview and i tried by converting each page into image but i feel its not a good way and it make my application big and complex.
Is there any way to create custom pdf view in 
suggest me some link and tutorial
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously need a pdf renderer/viewer. Since core Android OS does not provide one you will need a 3rd party one.

Take a look at http://andpdf.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thanks Peter Knego. I cannot use it directly. I need the way to implement a pdf reader in my application. Like we implement webview

Comment: This project is open-source so you can copy any classes that you need.

Comment: It is GPL so no you can't just copy the code unless your code is also GPL

Comment: I just DL the source: it's triple licensed under `MPL 1.1/GPL 2.0/LGPL 2.1`. SO it should be OK to include in proprietary sw (as long as they do not change their code, just link to it).