# PDF Viewer Widget in Android

Tags: android, pdf, widget, viewer

I have to provide the functionality of showing PDF docs in my app without using any external PDF viewer. I know Android doesn't have such kind of widget and WebView can't load a PDF doc.

**So I want to know, is there any widget available which can be used to show the PDF docs in Activity (like WebView is used to show web pages)?**

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592384/custom-pdf-viewer-in-android

Comment: @Labeeb: I saw that post also tried the link given in that but it provides only the APK file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know, there is no such 'off-the-shelf' solution available for Android yet. You can of course download any third party PDF viewer's code and modify it as per your needs.
Some of the Open source PDF viewers:

- [IcePDF](http://www.icepdf.org/)
- [DroidReader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)

Answer (score 1):

This has already been covered at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use a WebView, but then use the pdf.js library to display a given pdf file. I doubt this would look very nice on a small mobile device since it's designed for desktop browsers, but its worth a try.

[pdf.js website and demo](http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/)

Comment: Thanks dear. I'll surely give it a try.